# How can I manage to make this input only integers answer and rejected string. This include .split()

Tags: python, split, integer

Good day everyone, I would like to ask about this problem which I need to make the outcome only Integers and not string

If I put string in the Input.. it will make error and If i place number it will print the number

example:

> num = int(input("Enter number only: ")).split(",")
>
> print(num)

Comment: Your example code does not make much sense, you can't `.split()` an `int`. You can split a string into an array of `str`s, then convert them to `int` but honestly I'm not sure what you are after here.

Comment: I am trying to split int... but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user gives a comma-delimited input `7,42,foo,16`, you can use a try block to only add numbers, and pass over strings:

```
nums = []
user_input = input("Enter a series of numbers separated by commas: ")
input_fields = user_input.split(",")
for field in input_fields:
     try:
          num.append(int(field))
     except ValueError:
          pass
for num in nums:
     print(str(num))
```

Comment: is it possible sir not to use try and except for that problem?

Comment: Unfortunately all calls to `input()` will return a string, and all calls to `int()` will return a `ValueError`, so there is no way to check if the input is an integer without passing over errors in a try block.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
user_input = input("Enter a series of numbers separated by commas: ")
input_fields = user_input.split(",")
int_list = []
for i in input_fields:
   int_list.append(int(i)) # you may want to check if int() works.
```